# Excel formula using Concatenate has too few arguments

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a formula which works great while referencing a single cell in Google Spreadsheets. When I carry it over to Excel, however, there are apparently not enough arguments ("you've entered too few arguments").

I've dug up all the info on Spreadsheets I can, but none of the functions appear to be foreign to Excel and I don't see any missing arguments, which means the formatting might be off somehow but after playing around with it I can't seem to find resolution.

Formula:

```
=Concatenate(if(A24<10,1,ROUNDDOWN((A24-1)/4-1)),if(OR(A24<10,(mod(A24-1,4)-1) <0),"d","d+"),ROUNDDOWN(if(A24<10,-(10-A24+2)/2,mod((A24-1),4)-1)))
```

Here's the section that gets highlighted after the error (the "1" between the asterisks):

```
=Concatenate(if(A24<10,1,ROUNDDOWN((A24-1)/4-**1**)),if(OR(A24<10,(mod(A24-1,4)-1) <0),"d","d+"),ROUNDDOWN(if(A24<10,-(10-A24+2)/2,mod((A24-1),4)-1)))
```

The purpose of this is to convert a static number in a single cell (i.e. 10) into a value in dice plus pips (i.e. 1d, 2d+2, etc.). This has no relation to statistics; the formula is built with its own scaling for a specific purpose.

Thanks for your help and the learning experience!

Comment: The `num_digits` argument of `ROUNDDOWN` is required in Excel, but is absent in your formula.  In Sheets, it is optional and defaults to `0`

Comment: Good info that I missed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel use:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(A24<10,1,ROUNDDOWN((A24-1)/4-1,0)),IF(OR(A24<10,(MOD(A24-1,4)-1) <0),"d","d+"),ROUNDDOWN(IF(A24<10,-(10-A24+2)/2,MOD((A24-1),4)-1),0))
```

ROUNDDOWN in Excel requires two arguments. number and places. Note the ',0' added after each of the ROUNDDOWNs. In Google places is optional. If not entered '0' is assumed.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Can't believe I missed the secondary requirement for the ROUNDDOWN function, much appreciated.